# JSON string is validated but SQL Server 2016 returns a validation error

Tags: json

This is the code that returned the error,
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 194.

```
declare @json nvarchar(200);
SET @json=N'["wclass",{"student":{"name":"Linda Jones","legacySkill":"Access, VB 5.0"}},{"student":{"name":"Adam Davidson","legacySkill":"Cobol,MainFrame"}},{"student":{"name":"Charles Boyer","legacySkill":"HTML, XML"}}]'
Select * from OPENJSON(@json)
```

SQL Server 2016 returns the correct result but the message says it is not valid and some error.

The validation was tested here:
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
RFC: 4627

Comment: That's longer than 200 characters.

Comment: You are right, there were more than 200 characters

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON is truncated - see the end of JSON:

`select substring(@json,194, len(@json))`

This will work:

```
declare @json nvarchar(4000);
SET @json=N'["wclass",{"student":{"name":"Linda Jones","legacySkill":"Access, VB 5.0"}},{"student":{"name":"Adam Davidson","legacySkill":"Cobol,MainFrame"}},{"student":{"name":"Charles Boyer","legacySkill":"HTML, XML"}}]'
Select * from OPENJSON(@json)
```